# CefSharp.WinForms "Dock =DockStyle.Fill" no effect, black edge.how to make the ChromiumWebBrowser fill the TBForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

```
public partial class TBForm : Form
{
    private readonly ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

    public TBForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.baidu.com")
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        };

        this.Controls.Add(browser);
    }
}
```

i got this result

[image]

CefSharp.WinForms
"Dock =DockStyle.Fill" no effect, black edge.

how to make the ChromiumWebBrowser fill the TBForm?

Comment: Add a border to the browser and you'll more than likely find it's occupying the whole space. More likely your running with a DPI greater than 1 for which you need to make your app DPI aware, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#high-dpi-displayssupport

Comment: See also https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1803

Answer (score 5):

Do you tried disable the GPU engine using CefCommandLineArgs?

When you declare:

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
```

before initializations:

```
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Try to add the nex line of code:

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
```

Answer (score 3):

My experience was this was caused from using higher DPI settings. I used the recommended helper method at the entry point of my application:

```
Cef.EnableHighDPISupport()
```

See here for more details:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#high-dpi-displayssupport

Answer (score 0):

Your windows screen resolution is not set to 100%.
See the image below:

[image]

This is because CefSharp is using GPU to render and will depend on your screen resolution setting.

using this will fix the rendering to host display highest resolution:

```
Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
```

And this will disable GPU rendering:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Comment: It's not nessicary to disable GPU acceleration,  it's actually the GPU compositor that needs to match the DPI awareness of your main app. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#high-dpi-additional-info